# Selection of the position of the variable

Tags: functions

I defined a function `funloglogplot` to make a loglogplot of a function (`function1`) depending on several variables

```
funloglogplot[function1_, xmin_, xmax_, numpoints_] := 
  Module[{list1, listRe, listIm},
         list1 = {#1, function1[eps1, 1, #1, R1ideal, R2, ordre]}& /@ 
         logspace[xmin, xmax, numpoints];
         listRe = {#1[[1]], Re[#1[[2]]]}& /@ list1;
         listIm = {#1[[1]], -Im[#1[[2]]]}& /@ list1;
         ListLogLogPlot[{listRe, listIm}, Joined -> True] 
        ]
```

Nevertheless I would like to be able to choose the variables I am using for the plot (in this case I plot `function1` as a function of its 3rd argument and I would like to be able to select the argument).
Can anyone see a solution?

Comment: Something like this? `f[x_, y_] := Sin[x/y]; funPlot[f_, var_] := Plot[f, var]; GraphicsRow[{funPlot[f[a, 1], {a, 1, 2}], funPlot[f[1, a], {a, 1, 2}]}]`

Comment: No. I would like to parametrize the argument of my function. It means to be able to put the `#1` in an other place for example like this  `function1[eps1, 1, 1, #1, R2, ordre]` (the `#1` is at fourth position this time)

Comment: Instead of `#1` I used `a`. What other difference is between my try and your intent?

Comment: Yes but how can I use the `Map` (or `&/@`) with this formulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a generic function `f` and the variable you want to plot it against and then use a replace inside the body of the `Module`. I am writing this without testing the code, but something along the lines of

```
funloglogplot[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_, numpoints_}] := Module[
  {list1, listRe, listIm}, 
  list1 = {#1, (f /. x -> #1)} & /@ logspace[xmin, xmax, numpoints];
  listRe = {#1[[1]], Re[#1[[2]]]} & /@ list1;
  listIm = {#1[[1]], -Im[#1[[2]]]} & /@ list1;
  ListLogLogPlot[{listRe, listIm}, Joined -> True]
]
```

Might do the trick. (You might have to tune the `f /. x -> #1` assignment part. I remember it can be tricky).

You will then call your procedure specifying all parameters in  your function except the variable one which you can call any name (`x`, for example, or `z` - you just have to be consistent) as in

```
funloglogplot[function1[eps1, 1, 1, z, R2, ordre], {z, 2, 6, 120}]
```

I hope this is pointing you in the right direction. It worked for me when I created my plotting routines (now, the problem is: am I recalling it correctly?)

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you very much